# Combination of \listoffigures and inline math expression in \caption generates error

Tags: table-of-contents, captions

Do you know why I get error

```
! Missing $ inserted.<inserted text>$ ...}\mathsurround \z@ $\relax $.\relax }}{11}
! Missing $ inserted.<inserted text>$ ...}\mathsurround \z@ $\relax $.\relax }}{11}
etc.
```

when in figure caption I have

```
\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \includegraphics[scale=1]{rysunki/Figure_9.eps}
 \caption{Two-stepped cantilever loaded axially with the force $\underline{\mathbf{P}}$.}
 \label{fig:wspornik}
\end{figure}
```

and put `\listoffigures` in my `tex` file?

If I remove `\listoffigures` everything is fine.

Comment: fragile command in moving argument, use `\protect\underline`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you load the `etoolbox` package and issue the instruction

```
\robustify{\underline}
```

in the preamble.

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify{\underline}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}[h]
   \centering
   \includegraphics[scale=1]{rysunki/Figure_9.eps}
   \caption{Two-stepped cantilever loaded axially with the force $\underline{\mathbf{P}}$}
   \label{fig:wspornik}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The second upvote on this answer, received on 11/30/2023, raised my rep point total to just over 495k. Many thanks!